# open source asset tracking auditing for servers and workstations

Tags: audit, asset-management, workstation-management

need something quick and free for both domain based and workgroup based auditing of pc's and their hardware. all i want is hdd size, cpu and memory. doesn't have to be pretty just easy to deploy on the network. if an agent is required no big deal.
gd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [LanSweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/) with great results.  It definitely provides more information than you are asking for, but it is free and seems to be pretty reliable.

Comment: that looks sweep, i love this website ! serverfault rocks. thanks again guys.

Comment: A small nit to pick: LanSweeper is free "as in free beer", but isn't open source.

Comment: I know.  I was going to edit my answer to reflect this, but realized it probably wouldn't have helped anything.

It's not really a small nit to pick, regardless.  The ability to have access to the LanSweeper source to make adjustments and bug fixes would be very helpful.  Unfortunately, that isn't the case.

Comment: +1 to your comment re: not having source being more than a "small nit". I always like to hear others acknowledging the value of source code and a license that allows one to fix bugs (or pay someone else to do so).

Answer (score 2):

i'm happy user of [glpi](http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en) for tracking buys/licenses and [ocs-inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/) for gathering stats about computers.

for the second one - i use from time to time [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) that executes ocs agent which reports back all software installed and hardware components to central server.

Comment: yes you are right i have glpi running at another clients and have ssh back to the db so that i can run the agent, ssh into my server and pipe the data back but i wanted something less time consuming to configure. client is really watching cashflow. thanks.gd

Answer (score 1):

We use Spiceworks where I work
[Link](http://www.spiceworks.com) It is probably overkill for your needs but will do what you want and has reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a platform, so I'll assume Windows.

Give [psinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx) (part of the Sysinternals PSTools) a shot - feed it a text file with a list of machines to query, and an administrator-level username / password and output either CSV or plain text.  CSV and a little data munging should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

We use [lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com) for this, it's not full open source but if you have a premium license you are allowed to change the website (which is uncompiled asp.net code).

At my company we have created some new aspx pages successfully to connect the lansweeper data to our internal ERP system.