# Network-wide audit / discovery / asset tracking / license tracking

Tags: licensing, audit, asset-management

I'm interested in network wide audit info, and after some recommendations:

- OS (mainly windows; ideally server and workstation)
- apps (for license tracking)
- etc

Happy to consider free and commercial (although free [covered here](https://serverfault.com/questions/36612/open-source-asset-tracking-auditing-for-servers-and-workstations)) - or even outsourced as a service. Any to love? to avoid?

A pretty wide network, so it would *have* to be used centrally; walking around with a memory stick is not an option. It is an AD domain, so GP (etc) based options should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also check out [Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com), it's free and works pretty well.

Comment: I make good use of spiceworks myself, it helps and can collect a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

I been trying to learn and use Splunk for log analyse (also for PCI auditing), I also use Whatsup Gold to monitor and sort of keep an inventory of all our equipment.

http;//splunk.com

http;//whatsupgold.com

Whatsup gold and splunk both install pretty easy on Windows Server environments. However i'm not sure what you would use for key/license management.

Good luck!

-Stephen